# No consigo recibir el array de una consulta AJAX

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery, ajax

Estoy con un formulario donde quiero recuperar la contraseña de un usuario por medio de una pregunta secreta, pero estoy estancado, en la parte donde envió la cedula (identificador único del usuario) por medio de **AJAX** a una consulta en **PHP** para luego traerme el **array** (consulta de la BD) con la pregunta correspondiente de ese usuario registrado.

**HTML:**

```
<label for="user_cedula">Cedula</label>
<input type="text" id="user_cedula" name="user_cedula" minlength="7" maxlength="8" title="Debe ser numérico" required pattern="[0-9]+">
<button type="button" id="search_user">Buscar</button>
</br>
<label for="re_question">Pregunta de seguridad</label>
<input type="text" id="re_question" name="re_question" minlength="4"  required pattern="[a-z Ññ A-Z]+">
</br>
<label for="re_answer">Respuesta</label>
<input type="password" id="re_answer" name="re_answer" minlength="4" required pattern="[a-z Ññ A-Z]+">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es ingresar la cedula, con el botón buscar se envía a la consulta y luego mostrar en el input la pregunta correspondiente a esa cedula (usuario).

**Javascript:**

```
$("#search_user").click(function(){
    var id = $('#user_cedula').val();
    getUser(id);
});

function getUser(id){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'restore_row.php',
    data: {id:id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      $('#re_question').val(response.question);
    }
  });
}
```

La consulta en **PHP** `restore_row.php`:

```
<?php 
include 'includes/session.php';

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE cedula = '$id'";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();   

    echo json_encode($row);?>
```

**Base de datos:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has probado que te imprime dicho json_encode y que recibes haciendo un console.log() del response?.

Comment: @EduardoJavierMaldonado recibo Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: Prueba agregango esto después del cierre de las llaves del success: `error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(error);
  }` para que veas que te muestra de errror.

Comment: OK
index.php:662 parsererror
index.php:663 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Qb (jquery.min.js:4)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: el valor de cedula es entero o cadena? lo digo por la consulta sql que tienes... Si la englobas en '' se espera que sea cadena, si es un entero debes retirar las ''

Comment: Desde hay ya te creo el JSON mal, ya verificaste que lo que te está regresando el $query sea valido?, o sea ya hiciste un var_dump($row) para verificar que si este regresando bien los datos.

Comment: @EduardoJavierMaldonado donde colocaría el var_dump($row)? para saber si guarda el array

Comment: O sea ya tienes el json_encode, pero lo detecta como invalido, eso quiere decir que $row no es un array como tal, por eso te digo que hagas el var_dump. Incluso puedes cambiar tu POST por GET (temporal) para que hagas una prueba directamente en el browser, visita tu url /restore_row.php?id=2 o el id que sea y verifica que el var_dump del row tenga algo. Ya que lo resuelvas de esa manera y veas que $row tiene un arreglo entonces ya puedes hacerle el json encode, regresarlo a POST y recibirlo por AJAX.

Comment: @EduardoJavierMaldonado efectivamente tanto con var_dump y el json encode ambos guardan el array perfectamente si lo envio por url la id que ya esta en la BD (restore_row.php?id) osea la consulta en si esta bien, osea que el problema estaría en el envio del id en el jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta tus respuestas lo que no está llegando al back es la **data**, la data la puedes enviar de distintas maneras:

```
$("#search_user").click(function () {
    var id = $('#user_cedula').val();

    function getUser() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'restore_row.php',
            data: {id: id}, // Opción 1
            data:'id='+ id, // Opción 2
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#re_question').val(response.question);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

O algo más sencillo:

```
$("#search_user").click(function () {
    var id = $('#user_cedula').val();

    $.post('restore_row.php', {id: id}, function(data, status) {
        // data -> contiene el objeto JSON
        // status -> contiene el estado: éxito, error, etc.
    }, "json");
});
```

Con esto no deberías de tener problema alguno con el retorno de tus datos. Incluso en tú **PHP** puedes crear un `if()` y verificar si tu `$row` no es un arreglo entonces retornas un `json_encode()` con un valor `false` y así puedes poner una alerta de que dicha cedula no existe.

Para imprimir tú json puedes hacerlo con:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
exit(json_encode($tuvariable));
```